# Word for singular boardgame or boardgame expansion, but not both

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an auction site specifically for selling board games, and I'm a big believer in ubiquitous language and that the right naming makes the code design stronger. This is why it is paining me so much that I'm struggling to think of a term for the abstract of an item in a lot.

An *auction* will have many *lots*. A *lot* will have one or many *items*. An *item* could be a boardgame or a boardgame expansion. When adding an *item* a user will look up from a list of boardgames and boardgame expansions. What is that a list of? At the moment I'm using the BGG term "[thing](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/BGG_XML_API2#toc3)" and I hate it.

The best alternatives I have are *product* and *box*. Both of which are improvements, but both vaguer than I'd like.

Edit: Trying to add a better example.
If I wanted to group things that could be cars or pick-up trucks, but not carrots, I could use the word vehicle.

Comment: If it contains items, then: *itemlist*.

Comment: The question is more aimed at a name of the items in the list. Item is already taken, so I'm trying to come up with something else that's more informative than another version of oojamabob

Comment: You are mixing concepts. An *item* cannot be further divided—unless every item is necessarily made up one one or more *pieces*, *parts*, or *components*. As soon as you get to a ***single item***, it cannot (normally) be described as the sum of even smaller things.

Comment: What's wrong with *item*? It's way better than *thing* or *oojamabob*. *game item*? *article* means "an item of goods": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/article. In auction terms: *object*—"Lot - This term refers to either an individual object or a group of objects that are offered for sale at auction as a single unit. Each lot is assigned a number in our catalog for easy identification during the auction." https://www.auctionsneapolitan.com/Auction-Terms-Glossary.html

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be talking about database tables. In which case: *auction* --> *lot* --> *item*. Then the table named *item* contains rows of items in the lot, identified by *item_id*, *item_title*, etc.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - your last comment is exactly correct. Separate from that is what that Item looks up from (hence the problem with using Item again). Item will contain a ThingId, which references the Id of the Thing table. Things are either boardgames or boardgame expansions, and I'm looking for a better word than Thing

Comment: I still think you can stop tabling at the *item* table and add a field for *item_type*, where possible item types are e.g. *game*, *expansion*, etc. You don't need a *thing* table. Don't all items — whatever they are — have the same possible fields? e.g. an ID, a title, a type, a description, a year, a manufacturer, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, the database architecture is fine, I just want a better name for the table. Product is winning at the moment, but I thought there might be a word that encapsulates a thing or a thing peripheral

Comment: As others have commented, you have a list of *items* since the elements of the list are *items*.

Comment: Item is no different from "thing", it could refer to anything. Maybe I've not given a good enough example. If I wanted to group cars and pick-up trucks, the word vehicle would adequately cover both, but still be limited in what it could be; a carrot could not be a vehicle, but it could be an item.

Comment: Just a thought, but i’m not sure i’d want to tie my whole auction codebase to boardgames.  What happens when a friend of yours says “I want to start an auction site for selling bicycles and bicycle components”  and you say, “Man, I wrote a whole auction system that would be perfect, except it only works for board games.”

Comment: I like "sets", but can see how that might be confusing when writing code.

Answer (score 1):

**[SKU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit)** or **Stock Keeping Unit** is the business/stock control term for each distinct item offered for sale. It can refer either to the item itself or a unique identifying number/code (which in modern retail often corresponds to a unique bar code). Commonly each separate item would be (and have) a separate SKU if it was sold separately: so a board game would be a SKU, and expansion pack 1 would be a different SKU, and expansion pack 2 different again. Of course it's not specific to board games and expansion packs. See also [Shopify's](https://www.shopify.co.uk/encyclopedia/stock-keeping-unit-sku) explanation.

Answer (score 0):

How about **menu item**? From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/menu), a **menu** is:

a: a list of the dishes that may be ordered (as in a restaurant) or that are to be served (as at a banquet)

b(1): **a comparable list or assortment of offerings** // a *menu* of television programs

**Offering** might also work.